# How can I split an a concatenated XML document?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to "de-concatenate" a concatenated XML document. I have reviewed various similar questions already posted, but I have an issue with mine that most other questions did not face.

So far, I have tried a variety of methods, none of which worked. The two main methods that worked for other questions was to split by lines, or split using a recurring piece of text in between the documents.

The XML document that I have is concatenated where each of the documents directly follow right after the other, and do not have the same number of lines.

My document is in the following format:
    
        
            ...tons of stuff...
        
    
    
        
            ...tons of stuff...

...and so on with about 5000 or so entries. The number of lines in each of these documents is different.

The code that I have thus far is quite primitive as this is new area for me, so please suggest something better:

```
inputfile = "split_xml_bucket/big.xml"
splittingtxt = '</document>'
filenameformat = 'file#.txt'

def newfout(filenum):
    filename = filenameformat.replace('#', str(filenum))
    fout = open(filename, 'a', encoding="utf8")
    return fout

file = open(inputfile, encoding="utf8")
lines = file.readlines()

filenum=1
fout = newfout(filenum)

for line in lines:
    if splittingtxt in line:
        fout.close()
        filenum+=1
        fout = newfout( filenum )
    else:
        fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

What this does is it takes the large XML file, and splits it based on the last tag ". I then go ahead and append that tag back on afterwards. This works, but i cannot open the document using ElementTree afterwards.

My ultimate goal is to have a scrip that can take a large concatenated XML, split that into individual XMLs, and rename the documents based on a tag in each of the documents.

Please and thank you!

Comment: So your big XML file contains something like `<document>...</document> <document>...</document>` and you need to split it to two files, each containing one `<document>`?

Comment: Ideally, split each individual document that all start and end with <document> and </document>, and then rename them based on a tag that is in each document.

Comment: It can be done with `BeautifulSoup`. But can you edit your post and add sample (short!) example of the structure of big XML file and expected output? (including the tag that the filename is based upon)

Comment: I have tried BS in the past and failed miserably! If it can be done with BS, you have my full attention! The XML is 3500 lines long, I do not know which portion you would want to see...

Comment: I added some example, maybe is this what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup to extract `<document>` to separate parts:

```
data = '''
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="1"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="2"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="3"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for document in soup.select('document:has(some_tag[id])'):
    print('Filename {}.txt'.format(document.select_one('some_tag[id]')['id']))
    print('-' * 80)
    print(document.select_one('outer'))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Filename 1.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<outer>
<some_tag id="1"></some_tag>
</outer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename 2.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<outer>
<some_tag id="2"></some_tag>
</outer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename 3.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<outer>
<some_tag id="3"></some_tag>
</outer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT (To write to files):

```
data = '''
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="1"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="2"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
<document>
    <outer>
        <some_tag id="3"></some_tag>
    </outer>
</document>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for document in soup.select('document:has(some_tag[id])'):
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(document.select_one('some_tag[id]')['id'])
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(str(document.select_one('outer')))
```

This will create three files - `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, each containing separate `<outer>` tag.

Comment: Almost there! How would I be able to use this notation to create new .xml files from the larger xml file?

Comment: @alkhalifas I don't know exact structure of the XML file, but basically iterate over `<document>` tags, in each `<document>` tag find the tag the filename must be based upon - open the file and write the tag you want into it.

Comment: Where I am getting stuck is how do I iterate over that and separate the files? For example we start at <doc> stuff </doc> and then <doc> second stuff </doc>, how do i isolate the first doc and "stuff" into one file, and the second doc and "second stuff" into another file? That is step one, step 2 is renaming the file, but we need to separate first.